# Decoding correct geographic data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, geojson, json

I was given a json file that contains information like as below (truncated version but complete in structure)-

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[3909262.46926247, -1770881.94706788], [3909261.06123541, -1770740.38745684], [3909401.80402645, -1770738.96964834], [3909400.38998219, -1770596.88864125], [3909400.38998219, -1770596.88864125], [3909539.73283601, -1770453.91231545], [3909539.73283601, -1770453.91231545], [3909824.04203656, -1770734.7109451], [3909404.6218828, -1771022.08945481], [3909263.87730952, -1771023.50751348], [3909262.46926247, -1770881.94706788]]]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"dtegranted": 1321488000000, "iss_date": "17/11/2011", "objectid": 1, "company": "Terrastone Limited", "lic_no": "ML0002", "layer": "Mining Licence", "exp_date": "17/11/2016", "address": "P.O. BOX 995, LILONGWE", "id": 1, "area_sqkm": 0.169516104612393, "district": "NJULI", "license": "ML0002", "area": "169516.104612393", "minerals": "Rock Aggregate", "contact": "CHILADZULU", "dteexpires": 1479340800000, "type": "Mining Licence", "statusgrp": "Active"}}]}
```

and said that projection format is UTM36S nothing else. Now I need to convert this data back into WGS84 and create a polygon shapefile.

I am failing to convert into WGS84 and I converted those json files into shapefile using global mapper(used UTM36S during export to shapefile) since arcmap fails but that pops up as below though global mapper was able decode attributes correctly from the json file but messes up with the geometry-

[image: demo]

I tried to convert those utm x and y data into WGS84 using python function as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343865/how-to-convert-from-utm-to-latlng-in-python-or-javascript) but it gives me wrong coordinate 
Please help-

Full version of data is at http://pastebin.com/embed_js/9FfDYxgN.

Comment: The UTM36S has such bounds: 166021.4431, 1116915.0440, 833978.5569, 10000000.0000 (see. http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32736/). And your data have  Extent: (3718683.627072, -1927945.606749) - (3986975.040208, -1086524.713981). You need to find out right projection first of all.

Comment: Malawi uses the Plate Carree projection geojson converted with FME to esri shapefile zipped here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9mStgOXbs-jbWhkQ0g4eVdUU1E

Comment: @Mapperz How you knew that the projection is plate carree- please.

Comment: It is the most logical projection for the country of Malawi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Location_map_Malawi

Answer (score 1):

The format is [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) with type [Feature Collection](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects)

If I use Python with the [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) module

```
import fiona
test = fiona.open("your.geojson")
# structure of test (fields)
test.schema
{'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'dtegranted', 'int'), (u'iss_date', 'str'), (u'objectid', 'int'), (u'company', 'str'), (u'lic_no', 'str'), (u'layer', 'str'), (u'exp_date', 'str'), (u'address', 'str'), (u'id', 'int'), (u'area_sqkm', 'float'), (u'district', 'str'), (u'license', 'str'), (u'area', 'str'), (u'minerals', 'str'), (u'contact', 'str'), (u'dteexpires', 'int'), (u'type', 'str'), (u'statusgrp', 'str')])}
print test.bounds
(3718683.62707189, -1927945.60674904, 3986975.04020849, -1086524.71398137)
len(test)
53
```

Therefore you have a layer with 53 polygons

First polygon

```
first = test.next()
print first
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(3909262.46926247, -1770881.94706788), (3909261.06123541, -1770740.38745684), (3909401.80402645, -1770738.96964834), (3909400.38998219, -1770596.88864125), (3909400.38998219, -1770596.88864125), (3909539.73283601, -1770453.91231545), (3909539.73283601, -1770453.91231545), (3909824.04203656, -1770734.7109451), (3909404.6218828, -1771022.08945481), (3909263.87730952, -1771023.50751348), (3909262.46926247, -1770881.94706788)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '1', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'dtegranted', 1321488000000), (u'iss_date', u'17/11/2011'), (u'objectid', 1), (u'company', u'Terrastone Limited'), (u'lic_no', u'ML0002'), (u'layer', u'Mining Licence'), (u'exp_date', u'17/11/2016'), (u'address', u'P.O. BOX 995, LILONGWE'), (u'id', 1), (u'area_sqkm', 0.169516104612393), (u'district', u'NJULI'), (u'license', u'ML0002'), (u'area', u'169516.104612393'), (u'minerals', u'Rock Aggregate'), (u'contact', u'CHILADZULU'), (u'dteexpires', 1479340800000), (u'type', u'Mining Licence'), (u'statusgrp', u'Active')])}
geometry = first['geometry']
print geometry
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(3909262.46926247, -1770881.94706788), (3909261.06123541, -1770740.38745684), (3909401.80402645, -1770738.96964834), (3909400.38998219, -1770596.88864125), (3909400.38998219, -1770596.88864125), (3909539.73283601, -1770453.91231545), (3909539.73283601, -1770453.91231545), (3909824.04203656, -1770734.7109451), (3909404.6218828, -1771022.08945481), (3909263.87730952, -1771023.50751348), (3909262.46926247, -1770881.94706788)]]}
```

[image]

You can plot all the polygons with Python (Cartesian system)

[image]

What about the projection ?

```
print test.crs
   {'init': u'epsg:4326'}
```

**By definition the projection of a GeoJSON layer without a spefified crs is epsg:4326 (WGS84)** and what is clear is that the coordinates of your file are not in WGS84

You can open this GeoJSON file with QGIS, GvSIG, OpenJUMP, ..., without problem using a UTM36S projection (or any cartesian projection), not WGS84

If you try [PosFinder Yo](http://projfinder.com/) (Find My Projection) with 3909262.46926247,-1770738.96964834 for example, there are some other solutions